# Show the thumbnails instead of the name of img with Symfony2 formbuilder

Tags: symfony, twig, sonata, sonata-media-bundle

I am making the form which allow a user to select a img.

Symfony2.8 with sonataMediaBundle/

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($form)
    ->add('media',EntityType::class,array(
            'expanded' => true,
            'class' => "Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media"
            }))
    ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Create Post'))
    ->getForm();
```

in twig

```
{{form_widget(form.media)}}
```

However it shows the radio buttons with only the name of img.

○AAA.jpg ○BBB.jpg  ○CCC.jpg  ○DDD.jpg ('○' is radio button)

It is not good design for users.

I want to show the thumbnail of imgs here.

Is there good way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way i can imagine is to actually check the radio button with javascript.

Your Controller :

```
//src/AppBundle/Controller/YourController.php

public function yourAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $medias = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Media')->findAll();

    $entity = new YourEntity();

    $form = $this->createForm(YourEntityType::class, $entity);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        //... your logic
    }

    return $this->render('AppBundle::template.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'medias' => $medias
    ));
}
```

Then in your twig file

```
{% for media in medias %}
    <img class="to-select" src="{{ media.pathToThumbnail }}" data-id="{{ media.id }}" />
{% endfor %}

{{ form_start(form) }}
    <!-- assuming you are using bootstrap -->
    <div class="hidden">{{ form_widget(form.media) }}</div>
    {{ form_widget(form.submit) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}

{% block javascripts %}
    <script>
        //assuming you use jquery
        $('.to-select').click(function () {
            var id = '#form_name_media_' + $(this).data('id');
            var media = $(id);

            if (media.is(':checked')) {
                media.prop('checked', false);
            } else {
                media.prop('checked', true);
            }
        });
    </script>
{% endblock javascripts %}
```

Comment: the jquery part may be improved

Comment: Thanks a lot for now I am still struggling with this though, your idea `to control select boxes with jquery` is the best hit for me.